# TYPO3: Custom user system a good idea?

Tags: typo3

I am quite new to TYPO3 and I received a complex task: build a frontend user system that can be managed in the BE with a 3-steps registration (user has to enter his email, then received the link to the registration form, then has to be approved by an admin...).

I don't really know where to start. Is it better to build everything from scratch or should I extend the "fe_users" and "sr_feuser_register" extensions with my own extension ?

Comment: Did you have a look at EXT:femanager?
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/femanager

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out :)

Comment: if you want this exact workflow you will get problems with the usual registration extensions as the have another order: do registration, (send email to user,) confirm email address, (email to admin,) admin approval. you might use two registrations: 1st do a simple registration with only email but email approval. with this *temporarily* account the user could do a second registration with all profile data and with admin approval.